# jquery accordion collapse on new tab open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

Im trying to make my accordion collapse on click on the next tab, I am having problems. I believe the code is correct, the tabs open. but if i click on tab 2 tab 1 remains open.

also the arrows are not pointing down if tab is open.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="aside-nav d-all grey-border ">
            <li class="aside-open-close active">
                <a class="aside-opener" href="#">tab1</a>
                <div class="slide">
                    content
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="aside-open-close ">
                <a class="aside-opener" href="#">tab2</a>
                <div class="slide">
                    content
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="aside-open-close ">
                <a class="aside-opener" href="#">tab3</a>
                <div class="slide">
                    content
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    // open-close init
function initOpenClose() {
    jQuery('.open-close, .aside-open-close').openClose({
        activeClass: 'active',
        opener: '.opener, .aside-opener',
        slider: '.slide',
        animSpeed: 400,
        effect: 'slide'
    });
    jQuery('.nav').openClose({
        activeClass: 'active',
        opener: '.nav-opener',
        slider: '.nav-slide',
        animSpeed: 400,
        effect: 'slide'
    });

    jQuery('#nav .drop').each(function(){
        var holder = jQuery(this);
        var opener = holder.children('a');
        var drop = holder.children('.drop-holder');

        opener.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            holder.toggleClass('hover');
        });

        jQuery('body').on('click', function(e){
            if(holder.hasClass('hover') && !jQuery(e.target).closest(holder).length) holder.removeClass('hover')
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Where do you set your accordion ? You miss that part of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your [ul] tag as accordion it works fine

Adding this

```
$('.aside-nav').accordion();
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/hpom8jek/1/)

Comment: Did you tried my fiddle ? This https://jsfiddle.net/berets/hpom8jek/1/ ?!
If you click on other tabs previous one is always closed

Comment: yeah i have, seems to work perfect, im going to look if im missing a jquery reference and when i try your answer through my local it keeps all tabs open, once i get it working ill accept your answer

Comment: seem to get Uncaught exceptions with $('.aside-nav').accordion(); but without it it works fine, apart from the tabs not closing on another opening

Comment: are you including jquery-ui ?

Comment: Yes i did, your code was fine. problem my end. ive just started again with the latest library, ill accept your answer as it works fine